# Javascript, function in function argument

Tags: javascript, arguments, undefined

Im doing a automatic form validation. But i got function in function and helping argument from for(),and on the first function x=0 in next,deeper function x is undefined
`

```
var check  = [ /[A-Z][a-z]+/g,
              /[A-Z][a-z]+/g];
function input()  {
  form  = document.getElementById('form');
  for(x=0;x<6;x++)  {    //Here is my x,and x=0
  form[x].onchange = function()  { // form[x]=form[0]
    content = this.value;
    (check[x].test(content))? alert('yes') : alert('no'); //here x is undefined :(
  };
};
}

window.onload = function loaded() {
  input();

};
`
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.form.(anonymous function).onchange

Comment: check array length is 2, in loop you are trying to access check[3],check[4] etc which are undefined

Comment: What is larger 6 or 2? Also classical closure in loop problem (google: "javascript closure in loop").

Comment: @Dinesh — No. In the loop they are trying to access `check[6]` (and *only* 6)

Comment: @4castle — Oh, so it is. It's less than not less than or equal to.

Comment: @dinesh array length doesnt matter cause even when i console.log(x) is undefined

Comment: @Quentin I don't think this is an exact duplicate since there's another issue here: `check.length < 6`. I mean even after taking care of closure this would still fail.

Comment: "Let" was everything i needed thanks, i didnt knew it